# What is the best way to patch a server Win2012R2 that has not being patched for 2 years?

Tags: patch-management

1-Native Windows Patch
2-Patch Management Software (Security Controls from Ivanti)?

Any other general advice on a sequence, timeline to perform this long patch?

Answer (score 2):

Just run windows update, it's no longer like 2008R2 and older.

It will detect and install the latest cummulative update, which include older's one too.